# What is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n^2 x}}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, exponential-sum, polylogarithm

Following [Passare: How to compute $\sum 1/n^2$ by solving triangles](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701039)
 I tried the following
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2} dx = \frac{1}{n^3}
$$
So we can write (with some help of Wolfram Alpha)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2} dx =  \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2} dx = \int_0^{\infty} Li_2(e^{-x}) dx = \zeta(3)
$$
where $Li_2$ is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm .

But is also true that
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{n} dx = \frac{1}{n^3}
$$
so that one can write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{n} dx =  \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n^2x}}{n} dx = \int_0^{\infty} ?? dx = \zeta(3)
$$
The problem here is the evaluation of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n^2x}}{n} = ??
$$
which I (and also Wolfram Alpha) don't know how to evaluate. Is this series known in the literature and is there any way to evaluate it or express it somehow in terms of some special functions?

Comment: You should look instead at the theta function $\theta(x)=\sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ having much more interesting properties than $\rho(x)=\sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-1} e^{-n^2 x}$. Then $\int_0^\infty x^{1/2} (\theta(x)-1) dx = \pi^{-3/2} \Gamma(3/2) 2 \zeta(3)$.

Comment: You may already know this but you don't need $\sum\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{n}$ to show that the sum is $\zeta(3)$; it's enough to show that the sum is $\sum\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Comment: I don't have a lot of faith it's a very well known function since even the series at $x=1$, $\sum\frac{e^{-n^2}}{n}=0.337\ 078\ 425\ 353$ seems to have no results [(OEIS)](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C3%2C7%2C0%2C7%2C8%2C4%2C2%2C5%2C3%2C5%2C3&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: @reuns What do you mean by "the theta function has more interesting properties"?

Comment: @asmaier It is a well-studied special function connected to a lot of deep theories. Your function is a modified version of it but it lacks most of its interesting properties.

Answer (score 1):

Let's replace:

$$x=y^2/4$$

Then we have:

$$e^{-n^2 y^2/4}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2+i n y t} dt$$

Thus, provided the integral exists, we should have:

$$g(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-n^2 y^2/4}}{n}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} \log \left(1-e^{i y t}  \right) dt$$

Extracting the real part and using symmetry, we obtain:

$$g(y)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \log \left(1-\cos (y t)  \right) dt- \frac{\log 2}{2}$$

Now getting back to $x$:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-n^2 x}}{n}$$

$$f(x)=- \frac{\log 2}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \log \left(1-\cos (2 t \sqrt{x})  \right) dt$$

or:

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \log \left(2-2\cos (2 t \sqrt{x})  \right) dt$$

This works numerically, even though the integrand has an infinite number of singularities.

Let's substitute:

$$t= \sqrt{x} u$$

$$f(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x u^2} \log \left(2-2\cos (2 u x)  \right) du$$

Now there might be a chance to integrate w.r.t. $x$ as well:

$$I=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty  \sqrt{x} e^{-x u^2} \log \left(2-2\cos (2 u x)  \right) du dx$$

But I somehow doubt the integral converges, though I will check numerically later.